# Prevent keyboard from showing character bubble

Tags: java, android

when typing on the keyboard a bubble appears to display the character that you pressed , I am looking for a way to prevent it from doing that !!

[image]

Comment: I googled a lot I didn't find a thing .. the keyboard is so close it doesn't provide a lot of options

Comment: That sounds like the kind of thing that would be a user set option, not something you can dictate in your code.

Comment: Can the user set this option ?

Comment: I don't know. I can't find anything obvious in the settings for my phone, but that doesn't mean it's not somewhere not immediately obvious.

Comment: I couldn't find anything on my device neither no solution , thx man :)

Comment: What keyboard is that at all? There should be an option in the settings. Otherwise download another keyboard.

Comment: I need that for an app .. I can't use another keyboard !!

Comment: In android you use a keyboard which, essentialy, is a separate app. So you can't modify it (unless the keyboard developer thought about it - but still, there are lots and lots of keyboard in Google Play, so I wouldn't count on it). What is the reason to hide bubbles anyway?

Comment: No body can see your password :) !!

Comment: Well, typed characters appear for a moment even in a password TextView, so the bubble should be your least concern. It's really not so much of a problem on a mobile device. If you don't want anyone else to see your pasword, just turn around;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the keyboard on android is just like any other app . you can install any that you wish.

therefore , there aren't many rules as to what other developers could do with each app. this one is one of them.

as far as i know , the only thing you can do is to give the keyboard a hint of what type of input you wish to have for the editText (and the keyboard app might or might not handle it the way you wish for it to) . other than that , you just can't force another app to work the way you wish .

however , you can always create your own keyboard , even built into the app . this way you can set your own rules.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer: you can't.

The long answer: it's usually customized by the manufacturer. We found some many differences across manufacturers within the same Android version. We concluded there is no point trying to customize the behavior. Even if you do find a way, it may work for that specific manufacturer in that specific Android version.

Even when you ask for the numeric keyboard with `<EditText android:inputType="number" ... />`, what exactly will be shown to the user varies by manufacturer.

If you find a reference to a documented API to change the keyboard behavior, I would appreciate a link to it.